# How can I determine the relative bearing to an NDB using the G1000?

Tags: g1000, ndb

For using an NDB, a pilot should know to MH+RB=MH. But I have never seen a relative bearing displayed in the G1000. Could you let me know where to see the relative bearing in the G1000?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm not sure why you would want to do this anyway. The G1000 can take you directly to an NDB in the same way that it can take you directly to any other waypoint. But having said that, my G1000 experience is in a C172 that doesn't have any ADF. In an aircraft that does have ADF, it may behave differently.

Comment: Are you asking for a digital readout of this information? The relative bearing is read from the HIS as the difference between the NDB needle and heading indicator.